# LoadLibrary() file path

Tags: c++, handle, loadlibrary

I'm trying to use the function LoadLibrary(...) which takes in a string to a filename (.dll or .exe) or a filepath. The issue I'm having is when the filename itself has multiple periods/dots.

Example:

```
HINSTANCE hInst = LoadLibrary(_T("..\\folder\\file.name.dots.exe"));
```

The handle is always null and I cannot simply change the filename in this case. Microsoft mentioned multiple periods in https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/324468 but I don't believe it works for the filename. Any ideas?

Comment: This is a relative path. So... relative to what?

Comment: This is a relative path to the project I'm working in. I have tested this relative path to work with filenames without any multiple periods

Comment: BTW... **Never** ship code like this. Always compute fully-qualified path and pass that to LoadLibrary().  Reason: security vulnerability.

Comment: You'll notice that the referenced article's solution is to compute the fully qualified path. :)

Comment: _"This is a relative path to the project I'm working in"_ But current folder during your program execution is most likely different so `LoadLibrary` cannot find that file. As @DavidThomas wrote - always calculate full path

Comment: Also, check out [LoadLibraryEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx) for more info., If you notice the length of the article and number of options it takes, you can sense the number of ways developers have shot themselves using LoadLibrary...

Comment: Thank you everyone for your responses, the full path did work! I probably didn't write out the relative path correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the referenced article, always compute fully-qualified path and pass that to `LoadLibrary`/`LoadLibraryEx()`. Not only does this work around the dot defect, it prevents a security vulnerability. Highjacking the current directory for your application can cause your app to run arbitrary code.

See [MSDN on LoadLibraryEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx) for a better understanding of the complexities of using LoadLibrary.

Comment: Thank you again David. Unfortunately, I think I'll have to figure out a different approach to my other problem that LoadLibrary helped tackle (another story for another time) since this is a shared project that requires relative paths. But this answers my question!

Comment: GetFullPathName() may solve your problem.  Tread carefully. Defend your customers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the gentleman's problem stems from multiple dots WITHIN A BASENAME, as in:

**c:\users\joe\elephant.doc.old**

There is, of course, the concomitant "mangled filename" convention that maps this into something like:

**c:\users\joe\elepha~2.old**

If you use the mangled filenames--which are visible from within a DOS window--you should have no trouble, my young friend.

Comment: that was my issue yes. As David mentioned, a fully qualified path will resolve this issue. Thanks for the suggestion for the mangled filename! (also *gentlewoman haha not man)